# passport.authenticate() in routing-controllers framework

Tags: typescript, express, passport.js

I am new to JavaScript/TypeScript development, and I am currently extending an express application with an Single-Sign-On login. The express app uses routing-controllers framework to handle requests and should use passport-saml for authentication.
I have already managed to get the authentication working with standard express routes:

```
export class SsoRoutes {
    public router: Router;

    constructor() {
        this.router = Router();
    }


    this.router.get('/login-sso', passport.authenticate('saml'));

    this.router.post('/login-sso/consume', passport.authenticate('saml', {
        failureRedirect: '/',
        failureFlash: true,
        session: false
    }), function (req, res) {
        // handle callback

    });
}
```

But I can not figure out how to use the `passport.authenticate(...)` method within the routing-controllers framework. 
Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

Solution I would choose is creating your own middleware which will handle `passport.authenticate()` (check out how to do it [here](https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers#creating-your-own-express-middleware)). Then you can use your own middleware with `@UseBefore()` decorator.

```
@Get("/login-sso")
@UseBefore(yourFirstMiddleware)
loginSso() {
    // ... something you want to do after passport.authenticate()
}
```

And the similar for second endpoint:

```
@Post("/login-sso/consume")
@UseBefore(yourSecondMiddleware)
loginSso() {
    // ... some other action you want to do after
}
```

For other solutions check [documentation](https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers#use-existing-middleware) of the framework you're using.

Answer (score 0):

When using the passportJS methods directly in the router setup, the request/ response/ next functions are consumed "magically" from closure.
Therefore, if you extract and apply them in another class, you will need to provide them explicitely.

**In the router class**

```
...
this.router.get('/login', (req, res, next) => this.authenticate(req, res, next)); // Called by user
this.router.get('/callback', (req, res, next) => this.callback(req, res, next)); // Called by OAuth2 provider
...
/**
 * Authenticate the user
 * @param req
 * @param res
 * @param next
 */
private authenticate(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction){
    this.logger.debug('Performing authentication');
    this.customController.authenticate(req, res, next);
}
/**
 * Callback after OAuth2 provider has authenticated the user
 * @param req
 * @param res
 * @param next
 */
private callback(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction){
    this.logger.debug('Callback from OAuth provider');
    this.customController.callback(req, res, next);
}
```

**In the custom controller**

```
/**
 * Executes the authentication using passportJS
 */
public executeAuthenticate(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
    this.logger.debug('Authenticate using passport');

    passport.authenticate('<strategy>', { scope: ['email', 'profile'] })(req, res, next);  // <== Here! See that the function is called using the parameters (req,res,next)
}

/**
 * Callback after login completion
 * @param req 
 * @param res 
 * @param next 
 */
public callback(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
    this.logger.debug('Callback from oAuth provider');
    // Ask passportJS to verify that the user is indeed logged in
    passport.authenticate('<strategy>', (err, user, info)=> {
        this.logger.debug('Authentication check done');
        if (err) {
            this.logger.debug('Authentication error');
            return next(err);
        }
        if (!user) { 
            this.logger.debug('Could not extract user');
            return next('Could not find user object');
        }
        this.logger.debug('Authentication succeeded');
        return res.json(user);

    })(req, res, next); // <== Here! See that the function is called using the parameters (req,res,next)
}
```